# Mapping unidirectional foreign keys in hibernate xml

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to create a Unidirectional foreign key mapping between two classes in hibernate.

I wish to have the `InventoryItem` object contain a reference to a `Car` object using a foreign key.

For simplicity these are how the classes are setup:

```
public class InventoryItem {
    private Long id;
    private Car vehicle;
```

```
public class Car {
    private Long id;
```

I have the following xml files setup:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name = "com.leasecompany.carleasingsystem.database.data.inventoryItem.InventoryItem" table = "inventory_items">
        <id name = "id" column="id" type="long">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <one-to-one name="vehicle" class="com.leasecompany.carleasingsystem.database.data.car.Car" constrained="true" lazy="false" cascade="all"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name = "com.leasecompany.carleasingsystem.database.data.car.Car" table = "cars">
        <id name = "id" column="id" type="long">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

It seems to have created some kind of link but it appears to be using the wrong column as the foreign key value as I am getting:

`No row with the given identifier exists: [com.leasecompany.carleasingsystem.database.data.car.Car#1]`

It seems to be trying to find a Car with ID 1 instead of the value in vehicle_id (which is 199)

Sample Car Record:

- id = 199

Sample InventoryItem Record:

- id = 1
- vehicle_id = 199

I can get it to work if I use a `<many-to-one>` with the `column` attribute set.

Edit:

- doing some research shows that somehow I can use the formula section of a `<one-to-one>` to use a different column